# $T^2$ and $N(T^2)$: What are they?

Tags: linear-algebra

What is $T^2$ and what does $N(T^2)$ mean?

Any help is appreciated.

The transformation is applied twice? Is that it?

Comment: What is $N$ and what is $T$?

Comment: My crystal ball is out of service today. Would you please provide more context? As it is right now it might be anything.

Comment: $T$ is a linear map, and $N(T)$ is the null space of $T$.

Answer (score 1):

$T^2=T\circ T$ sends a vector $\vec v$ to the vector $T(T(\vec v))$.

$N(T^2)$ is the set of vectors $\vec v$ of $V$ that $T^2$ sends to $\vec 0$, actually a subspace of $V$.

Comment: How is $N(T)\subset N(T^2)$?

Comment: @AetiusBarlaam remember that a linear map sends $\vec 0$ to $\vec 0$. Can you get it now?

Comment: If $x \in N(T)$, then $T(x) = 0$ and $T^2(x) = T(T(x)) = T(0) = 0$ so $x \in N(T^2)$.

Comment: @Arnaud How are the dimensions of each related?

Comment: @FedericaMaggioni I guess a good question might be, to help answer this dimension question, is how does the image change under a secondary mapping by the same map?

Comment: @AetiusBarlaam As you probably already know, if $V$ is finite- dimensional, then $dim(N)+dim(R)=dim(V)$, hence, if $N(T)$ is strictly contained in $N(T^2)$, then $R(T)$ strictly contains $R(T^2)$

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate a little on Federica's to the point answer: The notation $T^2$ means the function $T$ applied twice. That is, if $\vec{v} \in V$, then $T^2(\vec{v})=T(T(\vec{v}))$.

If $T$ is *any* linear map, then the notation $N(T)$ means the set of vectors $\vec{v}$ such that $T(\vec{v})=\vec{0}$.

Thus $N(T^2)$ means the set of vectors $\vec{v}$ such that $T^2(\vec{v})=\vec{0}$. We have that $N(T) \subset N(T^2)$ since if $T(\vec{v})=\vec{0}$, then $T^2(\vec{0})=T(T(\vec{0}))=T(0)=0$.